# Was there really a shuttle toilet training device with a "boresight camera"?

Tags: space-shuttle, astronaut-lifestyle, training, waste

Was there really a shuttle toilet training device with a camera looking up at the user's fundament? This seems a bit undignified to say the least.

Comment: “Fundament”. Never heard that euphemism before :)

Comment: see  "Packing for Mars," by Mary Roach.  It's a fantastic book about all the things NASA did to test what might happen to folks in long-term zero-g environment

Comment: Also check out various audio tapes of Apollo crew joking about a certain free-floating brown object which got loose.

Comment: @s3raph86 - It isn't a euphemism - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fundament

Comment: +1 for fundament. Knew it meant foundation and basis... didn't know it also had an anatomical meaning.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Huh. You learn something new every day…

Comment: Fundament is not a "euphemism".  It's simply a word.

Comment: So when people call me an a***hole they're really saying I'm the basis and foundation of everything. Amazing.

Comment: Derived from the Latin word [fundo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fundo#Latin). Brings new meaning to: "lining up for the toilet", and "we can see where you've been".

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, this was the Waste Collection System (WCS) Positional Trainer, located in Building 5 at Johnson Space Center, adjacent to but not part of the Shuttle Mission Simulator Fixed and Motion Bases.

The trainer was located in a small room with a code-locked door. The room contained a conventional toilet, a functional replica of the shuttle toilet, and the WCS Positional Trainer. (The conventional toilet was behind the gray door to the left of the image).

[image]

Due to the small size of the seat opening in the shuttle toilet and the necessity to achieve a positive seal between the user and the seat so that the airflow worked properly, correct positioning of the user on the seat was critical.

The WCS Positional Trainer had a camera and light in the seat as shown below.

[image]

The image from the video camera was displayed on the monitor in front of the user.  A placard on the wall gave instructions for use.

[image]

This room was a highlight of any informal tour of the training facilities.

References:

Personal photos except photo of seat is a screenshot from the video below, which I recommend watching for more information.

Comment: A german Shuttle astronaut told in a speech that the Shuttle commander asked every crew member before flight if the toilet training was done successfully.

Comment: I am _so_ disappointed that no scifi space captain has ever asked prospective crew or passengers were toilet trained.

Comment: @StarfishPrime at least in 2001 there was an procedural placard outside the toilet door on the Aries.

Comment: So, is there a sample image that shows what the "proper position" is supposed to look like? :)

Comment: @JimL. AFAIK the idea is to be centered over the hole.

Comment: Interesting, what happens if an astronaut needs to do No.1 and No.2 simultaneously? Was the system designed for that option? That must have required quite an acrobatic skill.

Comment: @LeoS to urinate, you used the hose visible on the functional trainer, not the hole in the seat. Each crewperson had a personal adapter for the hose.

Comment: @OrganicMarble IIRC  that was a toilet compartment which spun up to provide local artificial gravity

Comment: @CarlWitthoft in the book yes, in the movie no. https://imgur.com/a/1DwLql1

Comment: Like every other aspect of astronaut training, there was actually some formal lecture time assigned to this training "event."  The most important takeaway that I can remember, however, was "And, remember, don't allow anything to fall onto the camera lens!"  But, seriously, becoming "centered" was not a trivial task, due to the rather small orifice that was provided!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Was that _really_ a **closed** loop television system?  Some of us wondered about that...although, truth be told, the entire crew experience at NASA had a way of chipping away at any notions of personal modesty one may have one possessed...

Comment: @Digger I was hoping you'd stop by and comment on this.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Most scifi spaceships have some form of artificial gravity, so presumably they could just use an ordinary toilet that doesn't require any special training... (2001 being a notable exception.)

Comment: BTW @OrganicMarble 's point is that in 2001 the famous "toilet placard" is on that shuttle spacecraft, *not* in the spinning-wheel station.  BTW this being the internet age, you can, of course, speak or type *"close up of the toilet instructions in 2001"* anywhere and instantly see it and get full details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  See the book *Packing for Mars* by Mary Roach for a detailed and entertaining account.  The book is a journalistic journey through the field of human factors in spaceflight.

Comment: Also mentioned in a comment. I've requested the book from the library.

Comment: The book is a fun read. The author is a bit sloppy about her facts but it's entertainingly written.